# Can't select last value of array using ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have this select box defined in angular

```
<select data-ng-model="data.hours" data-ng-options="value for value in range.hours" class="dateSelect"></select>
<select data-ng-model="data.minutes" data-ng-options="value for value in range.minutes" class="dateSelect"></select>
<select data-ng-model="data.period" data-ng-options="value for value in range.period" class="dateSelect"></select>
```

And the controller to define the default values:

```
$scope.data.hours = currentHours > 12 ? parseInt($scope.range.hours[currentHours - 13]) : parseInt($scope.range.hours[currentHours -1]);
$scope.data.minutes = parseInt(date.getMinutes());
$scope.data.period = currentHours> 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
```

My default values arrays:

```
$scope.range.hours = [1,....,12];
$scope.range.minutes = [0,....,59];
$scope.range.period = ['AM','PM'];
```

Everything works fine, exept when the default value I want to select is the last one on each array
So if I want: 11 hours, 58 minutes, AM it works fine and the elements in the select are visible to the user.
If I want: 12 hours, 59 minutes, PM the boxes are empty and I get this when I inspect the element:

```
<option value="? string:PM ?"></option>
```

Can't seem to figure out what's the issue...

EDIT: Typo on range period array.

EDIT2: After trying everything I could think of, decided to change the range to an array of objects.
They are defined this way:

```
range.period = [{label:"AM",value:"AM"},{label:"PM",value:"PM"}];
```

the markup was changed as well:

```
<select data-ng-model="data.period" data-ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in range.period" class="dateSelect"></select>
```

The model is set this way:

```
$scope.data.period = currentHours> 12 ? $scope.range.period[1] : $scope.range.period[0];
```

Since I'm passing the entire object to the data I needed to add a workaround before submitting the data object to the backend so it will just pass the value selected.

```
$scope.data.period = $scope.data.period.value;
```

It's a shitty solution but it's the best I can do to make it work. Hopefully I'll find what's wrong with the previous implementation (Just want to know, out of curiosity now.)
Hope this helps someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote, which is probably breaking your code:

```
$scope.range.period = ['AM','PM'];
```

Comment: That's a typo here. Didn't copy/paste the code. Edited on the main post

Answer (score 0):

Please

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.range = {};
  $scope.data = {};

  var d = new Date();
  var currentHours = d.getHours();
  $scope.range.period = ['AM', 'PM'];

  $scope.data.period = currentHours > 12 ?  $scope.range.period[1] :  $scope.range.period[0];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <select data-ng-model="data.period" data-ng-options="value for value in range.period" class="dateSelect"></select>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet works (as many of the examples I've seen) but oddly enough it doesn't work on my code.
The range is built in a shared service I have and the data is built in the controller I have for this tab on the dashboard. Could that be related ? It seems crazy that it works fine for every other value except the last one on each array...

Comment: @Haltinpot try this `$scope.data.period = currentHours > 12 ?  $scope.range.period[1] :  $scope.range.period[0];`

Comment: Tried it, still the same issue.
If I submit the form the values parsed are correct despite not being showed to the user by default

Comment: @Haltinpot just add above you select in html {{range.period| json }} and tell me what you get ?

Comment: I get this:  [ "AM", "PM" ] which is the expected, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64068/discussion-between-haltinpot-and-sylwester).